# How to send email from a out of process background task

Tags: c#, uwp, background

I have a UWP out of process time triggered background task which successfully shows a Notification and gets data from an SQL Server database table.

However, the backgound task will not send a simple SMTP email although the code works fine in foreground.

This link says mail can be sent.

[Microsoft background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks)

Updated:

```
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Tasks.ServicingComplete">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent"/>
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Tasks.LookupBackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent"/>
            <Task Type="timer"/>
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

I have Executable..., System Event and Timer declared in the manifest.
Perghaps there is another declaration required or sending an email cannot be achieved?

```
using EASendMail;
public static bool SendMail(EmailModel emailModel)
        {
            SmtpEmailModel emailConfig = EmailController.EmailConfiguration();

            try
            {
                SmtpMail email = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                email.From = new MailAddress(emailConfig.EmailAddress);
                email.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailModel.ToAddress));
              
                email.Subject = emailModel.Subject;
                email.HtmlBody = emailModel.HtmlBody;

                if (emailModel.Attachment != null)
                {
                    Attachment attachment = await email.AddAttachmentAsync(emailModel.Attachment.Path);
                }

                SmtpServer server = new SmtpServer(emailConfig.EmailHost);

                server.User = emailConfig.EmailAddress;
                server.Password = emailConfig.EmailPassword;

                server.Port = 587;
                server.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

                client.SendMailAsync(server, email);

                InAppNotificationModel inAppNotification = new InAppNotificationModel()
                {
                    Header = "EMAIL",
                    Message = "Message Sent"
                };

                InAppNotificationEventHandler.InAppNotification = inAppNotification;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                InAppNotificationModel inAppNotification = new InAppNotificationModel()
                {
                    Header = "Email not Sent",
                    Message = $"{ep.Message}"
                };

                InAppNotificationEventHandler.InAppNotification = inAppNotification;

                return false;
            }
        }
```

For background working I also tested with the generic mail provider and exactly the same result. I usually use async operation but removed this for the background task. I tested in foregraound with no async and it worked fine for EASendMail and the generic mail. It's an office 365 account.

Comment: what does your declaration look like?

Comment: Updated with declaration. thanks.

Comment: What method do you use to send the mail? Could you please provide us code snippet to test?

Comment: Have you trieed to use the `SendMailToQueue` method?
This method use the internal Queue system and could be better than the _interactive_ SendMail method.

Comment: Thanks for your help but SMTP is no longer an option.